# How to augment interfaces with functions in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
export interface Attribute {
  name: string;
}
```

With this I can use this syntax to create an `Attribute`:

```
const attr: Attribute = {
  name: "foo"
};
```

My problem is that I don't want to use classes because they are clumsy and not flexible enough, but I want to keep using the syntax above for creating objects because it is very succinct. I've read that it is possible to do declaration merging so I tried to do this to add a new function to this interface:

```
import { Attribute } from "./Attribute";

declare module "./Attribute" {
  interface Attribute {
    matches(other: Attribute): boolean;
  }
}

Attribute.prototype.matches = function (other: Attribute): boolean {
  return this.name === other.name;
};
```

The problem here is that there is no `prototype` to augment since interfaces are not available at runtime. If I merge the `Attribute` interface with a class:

```
export class Attribute {}

export interface Attribute {
  name: string;
}
```

there is a prototype and the augmentation compiles but I still can't use it:

```
import { Attribute } from "./Attribute";
import "./AttributeAugments";

const attr: Attribute = {
  name: "foo"
};
// ^^^--- Property 'matches' is missing in type '{ id: number; name: string; }' but required in type 'Attribute'

console.log(attr);
```

Is there a way to somehow do this? What I'm aiming for is to be able to do `attr.matches(other)` instead of having to do `matches(attr, other)`. This way I could do function chaining like `attr.a().b().c()` instead of having to do `c(b(a(attr)))`.

Comment: do you know upfront all methods of `attr`?

Comment: You say that classes are not flexible enough, but it looks like you are just trying to create a class, but implicitly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure you need that complex declaration merging; a simpler explanation is that "interfaces are open-ended ([cite](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/interfaces))" so you can add functionality to existing interfaces.

Example:

```js
interface Attribute {
    name: string;
}

interface Attribute {
    matches(other: Attribute): boolean;
}

const attr1: Attribute = {
    name: "foo",
    matches: function(other: Attribute): boolean {
        return this.name === other.name;
    }
}

const attr2: Attribute = {
    name: "foo",
    matches: function(other: Attribute): boolean {
        return this.name === other.name;
    }
}

console.log(attr1.matches(attr2));
```

FYI, you would actually be better with classes for this. In my first example, I'm violating the DRY principle by repeating the `matches` implementation for each object literal. When using a class, the matches function is bound to the prototype, therefore there's no repetition.

Example:

```js
class Attribute {
    constructor(public name: string) {
    }

    // Typically this is called `equals` in other languages; i.e. Java, Kotlin, C#...
    public matches(other: Attribute): boolean {
        return this.name == other.name;
    }
}

const attr1 = new Attribute("foo");
const attr2 = new Attribute("foo");

console.log(attr1.matches(attr2));
```

If you *really* wanted to declare objects like that, you can also do this with the class (although it's not really conventional). The following code is an extension of the example, above.

Example:

```js
const attr3: Attribute = {
    name: "bar",
    matches: Attribute.prototype.matches
}
```

If you **REALLY** don't want to use classes, a `create` function might help (roughly equivalent to a class constructor).

Example:

```js
interface Attribute {
    name: string;
}

interface Attribute {
    matches(other: Attribute): boolean;
}

function createAttribute(name: string): Attribute {
    return {
        name: name,
        matches: function(other: Attribute): boolean {
            return this.name === other.name;
        }
    }
}

const attr1: Attribute = createAttribute("foo");
const attr2: Attribute = createAttribute("bar");
const attr3: Attribute = createAttribute("foo");

console.log(attr1.matches(attr2));
console.log(attr1.matches(attr3));
```

Comment: The point is that I don't want to redeclare `matches` every time. That's why I tried adding it to the `prototype`, but of course `interface`s have no runtime representations so I couldn't do it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll just use plain functions defined in the module where the type is. This is too much hassle just to be able to do `foo.bar` instead of `bar(foo)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From your code, `Attribute` is an interface. A type or interface compiles to nothing in JavaScript; therefore, you can't do like this in your question.

```js
declare module "./Attribute" {
  interface Attribute {
    matches(other: Attribute): boolean;
  }
}

// No such "Attribute" variable!
Attribute.prototype.matches = function (other: Attribute): boolean {
  return this.name === other.name;
};

const attr: Attribute = {
  name: "foo"
};
attr.matches(); // error, attr's prototype is Object, not Attribute
// because there is no constructor function or class Attribute
```

There are some ways to solve your problem.

(1) Always include `matches` method every time you create a variable of type `Attribute`:

```
export function matches(this: Attribute, other: Attribute): boolean {
  return this.name === other.name;
};
const attr: Attribute = {
  name: "foo",
  matches,
}; // works
```

(2) Use `Attribute` class but simplify its instantiation:

```
type ExcludeMethods<T extends object> = Pick<
  T,
  {
    [x in keyof T]: T[x] extends Function ? never : x;
  }[keyof T]
>; // without this type, "matches" method is required in the object literal!

class Attribute {
  constructor(init: ExcludeMethods<Attribute>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }

  name: string;

  matches(other: Attribute): boolean {
    return this.name === other.name;
  }
}

const attr = new Attribute({ name: "foo" }); // works
const attr2 = new Attribute({}); // error, name is required
```

If `name: string` property causes compilation error, add non-null assertion (so that it becomes `name!: string`) since we are pretty sure that non-function fields must be present to `Object.assign` to `this`.